# How to create a Flipbook in Houdini using only the Python source editor?

Tags: python, houdini

I have a scene created in Houdini and I want to save that as a flipbook to a file location (my desktop for example) using only Python scripting in the python shell/source editor. I have read the sidefx website on creating a flipbook [here](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/hom/hou/FlipbookSettings.html), but I couldn't figure it out, specifically, I don't know what ***scene*** is referring to in that example. Here is what I have written in my source editor. When I call the function, Houdini just shuts down and I don't know why.

```py
# create flipbook
fbsettings = toolutils.sceneViewer().flipbookSettings().stash()
fbsettings.output('$JOB/Desktop/test.avi')
fbsettings.outputToMPlay(0)
# Launch the flipbook
toolutils.sceneViewer().flipbook(viewport=None, settings=fbsettings, open_dialog=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small snippet to create a flipbook. I hope this will help you.

NOTE : Make sure your path directory are correct based on operating system.

```
cur_desktop = hou.ui.curDesktop()
scene_viewer = hou.paneTabType.SceneViewer
scene = cur_desktop.paneTabOfType(scene_viewer)
scene.flipbookSettings().stash()
flip_book_options = scene.flipbookSettings()

flip_book_options.output('A:\\flipbook.$F4.jpeg') # Provide flipbook full path with padding.
flip_book_options.frameRange((0, 5)) # Enter Frame Range Here in x & y
flip_book_options.useResolution(1)
flip_book_options.resolution((1080, 720)) # Based on your camera resolution
scene.flipbook(scene.curViewport(), flip_book_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

it´s the avi test it with "tmp.$F4.jpg"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30793477)